# Cannot create new android project - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Since my new Update, I cannot create a new Android Project.

I could not upload a picture of this, due to a lack of reputation points. But every-time I try open new project, android studio is asking:

```
java
java fx
-------
maven
gradle
-------
groovy
griffion
-------
static web
--------
empty project
```

I already installed everything new, looked for the SDK, gradle. Before the Update, if I'm starts new project android studio just asked the api or if I wanna use a blank activity, but now I have this problem.

I hope someone could help me, because its really annoying.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order to help others understand your issue, please post what version of Android Studio and/or Gradle you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Before getting to the menu you posted above, you should see the "Configure" option. From there, go to "Plugins" and check "Android Support". Then, it will ask you to restart, and Android Studio Setup Wizard will install that plugin so that you can create a new Android Project as you've described above.

Comment: Get a detailed step by step procedure,[here](http://www.androidperitia.com/create-a-new-android-project-in-android-studio/)